# Rules - Page redirect not working on "after saving new content"

Tags: 7, rules

Using Drupal 7.7 and Rules 7.x-2.0-beta3

The rule set up is:

- Event: After saving new content
- Conditions: Content is of type news
- Actions: redirect to url news

When adding a news story and clicking submit, the redirect does not happen and I get left with a 'Connection was reset' error in the browser.

Had anyone else this issue? 
Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Did you try this http://ghita.org/drupal-the-connection-was-reset.html ?

Comment: Do you happen to have Rules forms support for D7 installed?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of serious bugs in the Rules 7.x beta (frequent 503 errors). Release candidate just came out that fixes these bugs. Try an update to the latest module version and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help  you,

- In Drupal 7, once you created a rule
- For your reference I have created a rule to redirect to some page when ever the **article** is created.

  [image]
- Check the weight of the rule. If it is 0 then increase the rule weight. 
  Refer above image
- In rule action, make sure to check **Force redirect** option

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

you could forget rules and try

```
function my_module_node_update($node) {
if ($node->type == 'news'){
drupal_goto('your_news_path');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to the current version of rules currently 7.x-2.2

Many of the bugs from beta have been fixed.